# VSCode autocomplete/intellisense for strings

Tags: visual-studio-code

While working with a PHP or JavaScript file in sublime, if I type the following code:

```
$test = "Scott";
If($test == null) {
    $test2 = "Scott"
}
```

When I typed in “$test2 = ‘Sc...” Sublime would autocomplete “Scott” since it was a word it found as a string in the current document scope.

However, when I do the same test in VSCode, it doesn’t pick it up or offer any suggestions. Is this possible in VSCode? I have already turned on the quicksuggestions to all true in the preferences. I am not sure what else I could do here or if there is an additional plugin that I need to download. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this?

[image: word based suggestions]

My settings:

[intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) extension enabled

```
{
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
  },
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
  "php.suggest.basic": false
}
```

Comment: This is great! I uninstalled another extension I had and installed this one instead. Working great! 

There is one thing that is it doing though - if I type in pretty fast certain words in strings, it won't popup the autocomplete automatically. There are quite a few times I will have to hit Ctrl+Spacebar and then it will get the intellisense to activate. Is there another setting to make sure it always pops up? Or am I just encountering a small bug? Thanks for the plugin! Great job!!

Comment: I'm unsure why this would be. The extension is just returning a falsey result in this context as it has no useful suggestion and vscode is then providing the word suggestions. There are some improvements that could be made to return a falsey result faster.

Comment: The extension relies on a server so that could be a slight delay in the request. The extension have been updated recently, so you might want to try again, or follow the evolution on the [Github repo](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense).

Answer (score 9):

These are word based suggestions. They are controlled by the `editor.wordBasedSuggestions` setting.

However, word base suggestions will only show up when no valid language based suggestions are found (see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21611). JS should do the right thing inside strings here:

[image]

But the built-in php language support will still return language based suggestions inside strings, which is why the word based suggestions do not show up

Comment: This looks like it is the issue. Thanks for answering so I didn't keep on trying different things.

Comment: Actually, found a temporary solution in the git hub issue you linked to. If you modify
Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\workbench.main.js and then 

find
if(!h)return a.TPromise.join(r.map(function(r)

change to
return a.TPromise.join(r.map(function(r)

It will start working. Please note that the "h" and "a." above will vary. I had to just search for ".TPromise.join(" and then loop through the results until I came across the correct pattern to change. Now, I am just trying to figure out a way to apply this patch permanently until it gets fixed in the core code.