# VS Code HTML and JS syntax highlighting/intellisense inside strings in PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpstorm, intellisense

I'm currently using JetBrains PhpStorm EAP build for PHP programming and I would like to switch to VS Code.

I'm currently working on an open source project that heavily uses printing of JavaScript and HTML code inside strings. PhpStorm has a very useful feature, it has full syntax highlighting and intellisense/code completion for HTML and JavaScript code inside strings in PHP. I have the `Intelliphense` extension installed on VS Code, but it doesn't seem to support this.

This is how JS inside strings looks on VS Code:

[image: This is how it looks on VS Code]

This is how the same code looks in PhpStorm:

[image: This is how it looks on PhpStorm]

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve on VS Code? Or should I stick with PhpStorm?

Comment: You might find the answer to what your looking for [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872641/vscode-autocomplete-intellisense-for-strings).

Comment: @slashroot Not exactly what I'm looking for, that SO question is talking about word autocomplete on Strings. I want full syntax highlighting and intellisense/autocomplete fo JavaScript and HTML code inside Strings, like what PHPStorm does.

Comment: In JetBrains IDEs it's called **Language Injection**: can be automatic (as in your example: it detects the HTML tag and injects HTML inside; or via some markers that each language can support: e.g. for PHP it can be the label for HEREDOC/NOWDOC .. or via `#[Language]` attribute for specific parameter etc; for Twig it's a custom block name. etc) or manual (a comment just before the string e.g. `$a = /* @lang SQL */ 'some text that is treated as SQL';`

Comment: Try googling for `vscode language injection` and check the links -- they should give some links/ideas for such plugins or corresponding VSCode functionality. The first/start link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1751 and https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the information and the links. I could not find any available extension that does HTML and JS Language Injection automatically in string literals on PHP files, but it seems feasible to do it. I currently don't have enough free time, so I'll continue using PhpStorm, but in the future I'll try and work on it.

Comment: related but not the same question (not about inside strings): https://stackoverflow.com/q/45947972/11107541

Answer (score 1):

This may help for some situations:
Instead of ' or " you can use [Heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) syntax to get HTML highlighted inside PHP like this:

```
echo <<<HTML
<!-- Insert your HTML code here -->
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h2>Syntax highlighting using heredoc PHP syntax</h2>
HTML;
```

And it looks like this on vscode:
[vscode syntax highlight using heredoc php syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhMEU.png)